# Re defining a variable inputed earlier in the program

Tags: python

I've been working on a password system for just python 3.6 and this is what I've come up with so far:

```
users = {}
use = ""

while use != "q":
    use = input("Are you a registered user y/n press q to close program.")  

    if status == "n": 
         createLogin = input("Create login name: ")

         if createLogin in users: 
             print ("Login name already exist!\n")
         else:
             createPassw = input("Create password: ")
             users[createLogin] = createPassw 
             print("\nUser created!\n")     

    elif status == "y": 
        login = input("Enter login name: ")

        if login in users:
           passw = input("Enter password: ")


        if login in users and users[login] == passw:
            print("Login successful!")
            changepassword = input("Would you like to change your password?")
            if cp in ["Y", "y"]:
                newpassw = input("What do you want your new password to be?")

    else:
        print("User doesn't exist!\n")
```

I'm trying to get it now so the password previously entered is changed to their newly entered password.

Any idea what I can add so it changes the password for that user?

Comment: If you write `users["foo"] = "bar"`, then password for user `foo` will be changed to `bar`. Same works if you use variables instead of constant strings; `users[login_to_change] = new_password`

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add:

```
users[login] = newpassw
```

So:

```
users = {}
use = ""

while use != "q":
    use = input("Are you a registered user y/n press q to close program.")  

    if status == "n": 
         createLogin = input("Create login name: ")

         if createLogin in users: 
             print ("Login name already exist!\n")
         else:
             createPassw = input("Create password: ")
             users[createLogin] = createPassw 
             print("\nUser created!\n")     

    elif status == "y": 
        login = input("Enter login name: ")

        if login in users:
           passw = input("Enter password: ")


        if login in users and users[login] == passw:
            print("Login successful!")
            changepassword = input("Would you like to change your password?")
            if cp in ["Y", "y"]:
                newpassw = input("What do you want your new password to be?")
                users[login] = newpassw

    else:
        print("User doesn't exist!\n")
```

PS: I suggest you to use [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html)

Comment: Cheers it works perfectly just looking at getpass now.

Comment: Thank you @johnnu. Can you please also accept the answer? Thanks!